# Creating a JSON dynamically with each input value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I got a situation where I would like to read some data off a JSON format through PHP, however I am having some issues understanding how I should construct the Javascript object to create the JSON format dynamically.

My scenario is as follows:

```
<input title="QA" type="text" class="email">
<input title="PROD" type="text" class="email">
<input title="DEV" type="text" class="email">
```

The Javascript code I have so far goes through each input grabs the data, I am however unable to understand how to process from here on.

```
var taskArray = {};

$("input[class=email]").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("title");
  var email = $(this).val();

  //how to create JSON?

});
```

I would like to get the following output if possible.

```
[{title: QA, email: 'a@a.com'}, {title: PROD, email: 'b@b.com'},{title: DEV, email: 'c@c.com'}]
```

Where the email is acquired by the input field value.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Like this:

```
function createJSON() {
    jsonObj = [];
    $("input[class=email]").each(function() {

        var id = $(this).attr("title");
        var email = $(this).val();

        item = {}
        item ["title"] = id;
        item ["email"] = email;

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });

    console.log(jsonObj);
}
```

**Explanation**

You are looking for `an array of objects`. So, you create a blank array. Create an object for each `input` by using 'title' and 'email' as keys. Then you add each of the objects to the array.

If you need a string, then do

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

**Sample Output**

```
[{"title":"QA","email":"a@b"},{"title":"PROD","email":"b@c"},{"title":"DEV","email":"c@d"}]
```

Comment: Why to in these 3 examples i alway get this? 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonObj is not defined'

Comment: @Gino Did you copy paste or type? See the line which defines jsonObj.

Answer (score 20):

I don't think you can turn JavaScript objects into JSON strings using only jQuery, assuming you need the JSON string as output.

Depending on the browsers you are targeting, you can use the `JSON.stringify` function to produce JSON strings.

See http://www.json.org/js.html for more information, there you can also find a JSON parser for older browsers that don't support the JSON object natively.

In your case:

```
var array = [];
$("input[class=email]").each(function() {
    array.push({
        title: $(this).attr("title"),
        email: $(this).val()
    });
});
// then to get the JSON string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Answer (score 11):

May be this will help, I'd prefer pure JS wherever possible, it improves the performance drastically as you won't have lots of JQuery function calls.

```
var obj = [];
var elems = $("input[class=email]");

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    var id = this.getAttribute('title');
    var email = this.value;
    tmp = {
        'title': id,
        'email': email
    };

    obj.push(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Big + 1 went with this solution the accepted answer caused me some issues in IE

Answer (score 1):

same from above example - if you are just looking for json (not an array of object) just use

```
function getJsonDetails() {
      item = {}
      item ["token1"] = token1val;
      item ["token2"] = token1val;
      return item;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(getJsonDetails()))
```

this output ll print as (a valid json)

```
{ 
   "token1":"samplevalue1",
   "token2":"samplevalue2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
// Sample JS object
var varobject = {
  name: "Name", 
  Intern: "Test", 
};

// Converting JS object to JSON string
JSON.stringify(varobject);
```