# Reformatting an array for jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array that looks like this:

```
thing1,thing2,thing3
```

I need to reformat it to look like this:

```
[ 
{ value: 'thing1', data: 'thing1' }, 
{ value: 'thing2', data: 'thing2' }, 
{ value: 'thing3', data: 'thing3' }, 
]
```

My current function looks like this, but clearly isn't working:

```
function combine_ids(ids) {
   return (ids.length ? " [ { value: '" + ids.join("'," + " data: '" + ids + " ' } ] ")  : "");
}
```

Comment: Check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009448/creating-a-json-dynamically-with-each-input-value-using-jquery

Comment: @MuhammadBilal, that has nothing to do with what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you array looks like this

```
var arr = ["thing1","thing2","thing3"]
```

You can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this

```
var result = arr.map(function(item){ 
  return {"value": item, "data": item}; 
});
```

which will return this

```
[
 {"value":"thing1","data":"thing1"},
 {"value":"thing2","data":"thing2"},
 {"value":"thing3","data":"thing3"}
]
```

---

You can alter your method like this

```
function combine_ids(arr){
  return arr.map(function(item){ 
     return {"value": item, "data": item}; 
  });
}

var result = combine_ids(arr);
```

---

```js
var arr = ["thing1","thing2","thing3"]
function combine_ids(arr){
  return arr.map(function(item){ 
     return {"value": item, "data": item}; 
  });
}

var result = combine_ids(arr);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function combine_ids(ids) {
    var Aobj=[];
    for (var x in ids){
       Aobj.push({'value':ids[x],'data' : ids[x]})
    }
    return Aobj;
}

combine_ids(['thing1','thing2','thing3'])
```