# Making a .Json file dynamically when user enters new data (Server side Parse.com)

Tags: php, android, parse-platform, json

I tried alot n explored alot but didnt got anything so i m asking here .

I m making an app in which users can create new events.

In that app any of the users can create an event . i m using parse.com for backend coding . I saved all data entered by user such as Event name discription in a parse object .

Now i m using facebook like new feed in my homepage which takes data from .json file that i have uploaded in server .

What i want to do is i want to update data in .json file in my server dynamically as soon as user fill up the form to create event .
[image: Snapshot For Event Creation]
Also  i wanted to ask if i can upload that .json file in parse.com ??

This is my .json file - http://collegebox.esy.es/android_login_api/include/untitled%20folder/abcd.json

Any Type of help will be appreciated .
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: what is there to give a downvote ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just know that you have to use php for that and better setup your own server .

This que has been answered already here [Creating a JSON dynamically with each input value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009448/creating-a-json-dynamically-with-each-input-value-using-jquery)

Hope it helps you

Thanks