# jeasyui datagrid insertrow with string format json

Tags: jquery, json, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am inserting a last row to a datagrid from JSON created in javascript (code copied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009448/creating-a-json-dynamically-with-each-input-value-using-jquery))
I was able to produce this

```
 {amountA:'99,865.65', amountB:'47,781.91', amountTotal:'147,647.56'}
```

To insert,

```
function insertRow(index, thisRow) {
$("#tDataGrid").datagrid('insertRow', {
    index: index,
    row: thisRow
});
```

This doesn't work, but when I copied the produced JSON to the code like

```
     index: index,
     row:  {amountA:'99,865.65', amountB:'47,781.91', amountTotal:'147,647.56'}
```

it works perfectly.

What's wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still having problem. Don't know what to do. It seems to be really simple, but sometimes, simple things are the most complicated and hard to resolve. :'(

Comment: If you're still having the problem, please post a simple example showing a call to insertRow that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try this way to add in general*

```
$('#tDataGrid').datagrid({
data: [
    {amountA:'value11', amountB:'value12', amountC:'value12'},
    {amountA:'value11', amountB:'value12', amountC:'value12'}
]
});
```

*Append a new row. The new row will be added to the last position:*

```
$('#tDataGrid').datagrid('appendRow',{
amountA: 123,
amountB: 123,
amountC: 'some Text'
});
```

*Insert a new row at second row position.*

```
$('#tDataGrid').datagrid('insertRow',{
index: 1,   // index start with 0
row: {
    amountA: 123,
    amountB: 123,
    amountC: 'some Text'
}
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much what the OP is doing, isn't it?

Comment: Its pretty much the same, he could try Data object without using Row Object.  If he is sending many JSON rows to 'thisRow' then it would be a problem