# wants to create json data from Jquery Array

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

How to Create this type of JSON data from Jquery array

```
$('.checkedvalue').each(function() { 
            dataname = $(this).data('value');
            key = $(this).data('key');

            array_variable = dataname +'_array';

            var array_variable = [];

            class_label = dataname +'_label';

            var class_label = [];

            $('.'+dataname).each(function()
            {

                if($(this).is(':checked'))
                {
                    var value_class = $(this).attr('class');
                    // console.log($(this).data('classlabel'));
                    // console.log(value_class);
                    if(value_class == dataname)
                    {
                        array_variable.push($(this).val());
                        class_label.push($(this).data('classlabel'));

                        jsonObj[key] =  dataname,
                        jsonObj[class_label] =  array_variable;


                    }

                }
            });
        // console.log(class_label);
        });
```

**JSON**:

```
{
    "Website Info":"website_contact",
    {
        "Display" : "index",
        "Insert"  : "add",
        "Login" : "login"
    };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: Go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009448/creating-a-json-dynamically-with-each-input-value-using-jquery

Comment: I want to change my key every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script>
    var permissions = {};

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#save_role_permission").click(function() 
        {
            var role = $("#role").val();
            var class_name;
        
            $('.checkedvalue').each(function()
            { 
                
                var controller_val = [];

                class_name = $(this).data('value');
                controller_label  = $(this).data('key');

                $('.' + class_name).each(function()
                {
                    
                    if($(this).is(':checked'))
                    {
                        var value_class = $(this).attr('class');
                        method_label = $(this).data('classlabel');
                        method_name = $(this).val();

                        permissions[controller_label] = [];
                        permissions[controller_label].push({[controller_label]:class_name});
                        
                        if(value_class == class_name)
                        {
                            controller_val.push({[method_label]:method_name});
                            permissions[controller_label].push(controller_val);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });          
            // console.log(permissions);
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(permissions));
            // return false;
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/roles/add_role_permission',
                type: 'POST',
                // dataType: 'json',
                // contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    role: role,
                    permissions:JSON.stringify(permissions),
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    // console.log(data);
                   location.reload(true);
                }
            });
        });
    });   


</script>
```